# Body as a power supply

Tags: power-supply, wearable

First question is does our body actually generate current?

My guess is that it's a yes, we're technically a walking battery. I know that if I touch probes of a multimeter, we can measure some kind of voltage. It's usually not stable but there is actually something to measure.

I was wondering exactly how much current can we get from our own body. I remember I saw a video where a person touches his oscilloscope and said that the sinewave he sees is actually the current from the main that is capted by his body. Because in reality, the body is also a good antenna.

So what I really wanted to know, how much current can we get from our own body. Could that be enough to power small devices such as a watch or other kind of wareables.

If the body produce electric energy, is it affected by the body activity. For example, at rest we produce lest energy than while running.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure it is possible because EKG/ECG actually work by measuring heart's electricity.

Now if that was possible to power a device from our body's electricity. Would that be harmful? I guess we don't produce energy for nothing.

Comment: Short answer: yes, we produce electricity (and absorb some AC via capacitive coupling), and no, it's not enough for anything useful. A much better bet would be to install a Peltier element in the watch, but that would only work in winter.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev get a bunch of us together and we can power robots. See IEEE '99 paper 'The Matrix'

Comment: @efox29 That scene is in the movie only to give the impression that there is a purpose in human existence. Oh well, it's fiction movie after all.

Comment: you are better off trying to convert our motion or something in shoes that we step on.  and still wont be a whole lot.  Energy cannot be created nor destroyed, so no it wouldnt be free you steal energy from the body you have to compensate for it by consuming that much more.  I like the peltier watch thing, but not sure it would power a watch.

Comment: There is actually serious research on this, for powering medical systems embedded in the body.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yes, I thought of that, but that sounds pointless if it works in certain conditions.

Answer (score 4):

No, we are not a walking battery and we don't generate the voltage seen when we touch probes - that voltage is due to capacitance between our bodies and the wiring in our homes/labs and ground.

The only current our bodies generate is to control muscle activity. This is measured as a signal by ECG machines and measuring that signal produces almost virtually useless amounts of power - enough to be amplified and displayed but not enough for any practical purposes.

Comment: *The only current our bodies generate is to control muscle activity* - Well, not exactly. Any neural activity is generating current, not necessarily just the muscle control. Like the sensoric signals or even the brain processes.

Comment: For the probe things. That's what I thought. But could it be possible to use that energy that our body receive.

Comment: Your question is too open-ended... use for "what" and how much energy does "what" need?

Comment: Hard to say, it's more about how much we can get from it than trying to power something particular. That way, something can be designed around the limitations...

Comment: There is a comment under your question from pjc50 that seems somewhat promising so maybe try and attract his attention on this subject.